# Membership and SQL question

Tags: asp.net, sql, membership

I am thinking of following what buttons the user has pressed. I intend to choose the CreateUserWizard control that will create a database for me. The Membership class has got a few functions to identify who the user is..e.g. GetUserNameByEmail..

What i am trying to do, is to track what each user has pressed and use his input for sqlCommand. 
For example, when the user presses the "post response" button, i want to record his identity and use it in sql to insert his message and identity..

The problem is that in the Users table that i made it has UserID as a primary key that identifies the user..and in the CreateUserWizard database or Membership cookie, it has its own functions fields.

So the question is how do i SELECT the users identity from the database/cookie created to me, and incorporate it into a statement in the SQL for my sqlStatement..

I need to obtain the identity of the user and use it in an SQL statement.. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the user_id from the Membership provider...

for example:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

the will give you the user id of the current user - and you can use that value in your sql statement.  If you're using the default Membership provider - this value will be a unique identifier (Guid) so:

```
Guid currentUserId = new Guid(System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
```

Comment: So the Membership class (that makes the cookie) is what supplies me the ID..which i feed in all my sql commands. I guess i may not need the user table that i created...or should i keep it, cause it is connected to my threads and posts tables.. what do you think?

Comment: Another thing.. How does the ProviderUserKey increments? does it go by 1 each time? or is it something random like a hashcode?